# Is there a bib entry type in biblatex-chicago for one author's chapter in someone else's single-author book?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

I would like to create a `.bib` entry for a chapter written by one person (Ronny Vollandt) as part of someone else's single-author book (Ahmad Al-Jallad's *The Damascus Psalm Fragment*, Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2019), using a `crossref` to that book.

(I know about `incollection`, which I use regularly for contributions to edited volumes; but those books have an *editor* rather than an *author*.)

I would like the note output to be something like this:

> Ronny Vollandt, "Beyond Arabic in Greek letters," in *The Damascus Psalm Fragment* by Ahmad Al-Jallad (Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2019).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, I just realized the answer to my own question, which I will record in case it is useful to anyone else:

The solution is to use `inbook` rather than `incollection`.

```
@inbook{vollandt,
  author     = {Ronny Vollandt},
  title      = {Beyond {Arabic} in {Greek} letters},
  booktitle  = {The {Damascus} Psalm Fragment},
  bookauthor = {Ahmad Al-Jallad},
  location   = {Chicago},
  publisher  = {University of Chicago Press},
  date       = {2019},
}
```

This produces the output

> Ronny Vollandt, "Beyond Arabic in Greek letters," in *The Damascus Psalm Fragment*, by Ahmad Al-Jallad (Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2019).

which is identical to what I asked for except with a comma after the book's title (which is probably what Chicago style requires anyway).

Comment: I added a usable example entry. Usually one would also give the chapter or pages information. I could not find the book on the UCP webpage and only found a version on Academia.edu which suggests `chapter    = {Appendix 1},` might be useful.

Comment: Thank you, that certainly improves the answer. I tested out `chapter = {appendix 1}` but found that it outputs "...chap. appendix 1 in..." Is there some macro one can use in the `chapter` field to prevent `biblatex-chicago` from adding "chap." when an alternative chapter name (here "appendix") is given?

Comment: Ugh, I didn't see the 'chap.' in 'chap. appendix', sorry. With the standard styles one could say `\DeclareFieldFormat{chapter}{\ifnumeral{#1}{\bibstring{chapter}~}{}#1}`. Haven't tested that with `biblatex-chicago` yet. If it doesn't work you could ask a new question about that ;-)

Comment: That did the trick -- thanks! (I also tested it on a bib entry that had just a numeral in `chapter`, and that worked as expected: "chap. 24".)